# Vandermonde convolution for the trinomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

Use a combinatorial argument to prove the Vandermonde convolution for the trinomial
coefficients:  If $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers and $a+b+c=m+n$ then

$$\sum_{\alpha+\beta+\gamma=m}\binom{m}{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}\binom{n}{a-\alpha,b-\beta,c-\gamma}=\binom{m+n}{a,b,c}.$$

I will be appreciated for any hint or start. 
I edited my post for correction.

Comment: please check my edit to be sure that I copied the sum correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is much the same as for the binomial coefficients.

Instead of choosing one group of $a$ people from $m$ girls and $n$ boys, choose two groups, one with $a$ people and the other with $b$ people.

In case you are confused by the formula: the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ is written as $\binom{n}{k,\ n-k}$ in multinomial notation. By choosing $k$, you "unchoose" $n-k$.

Comment: Salma, it _is_ true!! Don't listen to him!!!